# Git merge нескольких веток

Tags: git, контроль-версий

При наличии подветок и слиянии основной ветки с master, что произойдет с подветками? Как произвести слияние с произвольной веткой?

Comment: 1. ничего не произойдёт. 2. `$ git merge название-существующей-произвольной-ветки`

Comment: 1. ...потому что подветки реально ответвляются не от самой ветки, а от её состояния на момент ветвления. И что с этой веткой произойдёт дальше, совершенно неважно.